# Not getting groups claims even after setting "groupMembershipClaims": "All" in the app manifest

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

In my dev environment, I have my own AAD where I've registered my asp-net core application to enable open id connect authentication. I've edited the manifest so that:

```
 "groupMembershipClaims": "All"
```

It works on my dev environment, but when I do the same in production, I'm not getting the user claims. I've double checked the application manifest in production AAD and groupMembershipClaims are set to all.

What else could prevent from retrieving user claims?

Just to mention, we have on-premise AD that is synchronized to AAD. I'm able to retrieve groups created locally using azure powershell cmdlets.

**EDIT:**
I've figured out, that in production, number of groups exceeded limit and I'm getting these claims instead:

```
_claim_names:   {"groups":"src1"}
_claim_sources: {"src1":{"endpoint":"https://graph.windows.net/{someguid}/users/{anotherguid}/getMemberObjects"}}
```

Is there an ASP.NET Core sample how to retrieve the groups using GRAPH API?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure it may be caused by that you missed some steps or something else. You can refer to [this sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims/) to check steps.

Comment: Have you properly [consented the application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/application-dev-consent-framework) in your production env.? I Assume you are not global admin in your prod env. Make a global Admin to hit "Grant permissions" for your app. When he is reluctant - make him do this just for the test.

Comment: Which permission exactly has to be granted in order to get user claims? In my dev env, I've removed all the permission, clicked on "Grant Permissions", but I still get the user claims

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that there were too many user groups in production environment and AAD or Open Id  connect has some limit how many claims can it return.

I had to call MS Graph API  in order to retrieve user groups.